# DPAD on Android TV

Tags: android, android-webview, d-pad

I written android application on HTML (html files in assets, I show them with WebView)

```
    webView = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(webView);

    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
    settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

and I have the next problem: on some Android TV Boxes DPAD works, but on some doesn't work right and left DPAD keys.

For example:

- On Tomato Smart TV Box DVB-T2, Android 4.0, Cortex A9, 1024 RAM, 2048 Nand - DPAD works well.
- On Tomato Webcam X6, Android 4.2.2 Cortsex A9, 1024 RAM, 8 GB Nand - right and left DPAD keys doesn't works, up and down keys work.

How to understand that? I don't handle DPAD keys.

Comment: You would have to ask the manufacturer of the affected device.

Comment: Does the D-pad work fine in other html-based applications? What about non-html-based applications?